# iOS - Application crashes only when running directly on simulator but working fine while debugging or running through Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, ios-simulator

I've recently created a new framework project and moved many files to that project, now when I run the application it works fine on Xcode without any problem, but if I run the application directly from simulator (without Xcode) it launches and terminated immediately. I've checked simulator logs doesn't find any useful information related to that. Now I'm clueless. Any help or idea would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem, it was an linker issue, new frameworks are not linked properly, I've added those in Embedded Binaries section from General tab, it started working.